# Best way to save attribute inside save block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my controllers I often have functionality like this:

```
@account = Account.new(account_params)
if @account.save
  if @account.guest?
    ...
  else
    AccountMailer.activation(@account).deliver_later
    @account.update_column(:activation_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
    flash[:success] = "We've sent you an email."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

What's the best way to send an email **and** update the `activation_sent_at` attribute without having to save the record twice? Calling `update_column` doesn't feel right to me here because AFAIK it creates an extra SQL query (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: The workaround is using `assign_attributes`, but I would not recommend it. Your code is fine, and an additional update query to update the column shouldn't make much difference. Also, check like `guest?` can also be applicable on some model hooks which won't be invoked with assign_attributes. Overall cost of using it will be making it slightly unreadable

Comment: for optimization, you can send the mail via ActiveJob by configuring and using `deliver_later`; that will make it asynchronous. That will make sure your controller doesn't spend time composing, dealing with mail provider and sending email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is fine. I wouldn't change it.**

For example, you might be tempted to do something like this:

```
@account = Account.new(account_params)
@account.activation_sent_at = Time.zone.now unless @account.guest?
if @account.save
  if @account.guest?
    ...
  else
    AccountMailer.activation(@account).deliver_later
    flash[:success] = "We've sent you an email."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Aside from the small issue that there's now repeated logic around `@account.guest?`, *what happens if `AccountMailer.activation(@account).deliver_later` fails?* (When I say "fails", I mean - for example - `AccountMailer` has been renamed, so the controller returns a 500 error.)

In that case, you'd end up with a bunch of `account` records which have an `activation_sent_at` but were never sent an email; and you'd have no easy way to distinguish them.

Therefore, this code warrants running two database calls anyway: One to create the record, and then another to confirm that an email was sent. If you refactor the code to only perform a single database call, then you'll become vulnerable to either:

- Sending an email to a non-created user, or
- Marking a user with `activation_sent_at` despite o email being sent.

The controller *should* be doing two transactions, not one. Which is why I said: Don't change it.

Comment: The `after_*\before_*` callbacks is a better place for things like this one `@account.activation_sent_at = Time.zone.now`

Comment: @Зелёный Is it though, really? Just because it's a part of the rails framework, that does not make is a "better place". Writing `after_save :set_activation_sent_at unless :guest?` may make move the logic out of the controller, but it still causes the exact same problem I described above -- only now, it's even more convoluted.

Comment: Keep things clean and simple, thin controller, fat model.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't simplify things, in my opinion. Also, models should ideally be skinny too. If you feel there's a better way to write this, I'd be interested to see it in full.

Comment: I would think about adding a `send_activation_mail` method to `User` that does both - calling the `AccountMailer` and updating the `activation_sent_at` column.

Comment: Yeah, that's a sensible idea @spickermann. Probably overkill if this code is only used in one place, though.